# why reCAPTCHA thing coming when we use firebase phone authentication react-native android?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

why this reCAPTCHA thing is coming and i also tried to remove the reCAPTCHA still the same issue. can anyone explain me why it's coming and after adding in the play store will it go or still it will come ?

and now the safetyNet is depricated and play integrity has come. and i tried this method

added playintegrity in app check and added the sha-256 fingerprint.

still same issue

can anybody tell me how to remove and why it's coming?

thank you...f